# Sorting rows in T-SQL within report containing UNIONs

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008-R2 and Transact SQL.

I have a status report that returns data from multiple tables/views and use UNION to 'join' the rows together.

An *extract* from the SQL script is

```
    SELECT
    NR.FormStatus AS [Item],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport 
        WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus AND NotificationDate BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus) AS [Total]   

FROM
    NotificationDatesForReport AS NR

GROUP BY
    NR.FormStatus, NR.DisplayOrder  

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Distinct password requests',
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests
        WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests) AS [Total]
```

This works as expected, however, the order of the items in the first part of the script with the `GROUP BY` clause appears in random order. What I want to do is to sort just that section of the script but I cannot find a way to do it as the `SORT` BY clause has to go after that last UNION.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: So where do you want the `Distinct password requests` row to appear with respect to the sorted section?

Comment: This goes after the sorted section - I only want to sort within the first part. The other parts display in the correct order

Comment: SELECT * FROM (YOUR CODE TILL NOW) ORDER BY (YOUR_CRITERIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the whole thing in a CTE like so...

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT
    NR.FormStatus AS [Item],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport 
        WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus AND NotificationDate BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus) AS [Total],
    0 AS [Section], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NR.FormStatus, NR.DisplayOrder) AS [DisplayOrder]
FROM
    NotificationDatesForReport AS NR
GROUP BY
    NR.FormStatus, NR.DisplayOrder  

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Distinct password requests',
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests
        WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests) AS [Total],
    1 AS [Section],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ToEMail) AS [DisplayOrder]
) 

SELECT ***desired columns*** FROM cte ORDER BY Section, DisplayOrder
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. A working answer plus an introduction to Common Table Expression (which I was not aware of) as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that when you say "[X] goes after [Y]", you are *specifying a particular order* and so must make provision for that in your code.

I'm guessing that the first `SELECT` should be ordered by `NR.DisplayOrder`, in which case something like this should do the trick:

```
    SELECT
    NR.FormStatus AS [Item],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport 
        WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus AND NotificationDate BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(PerinatalReportID) FROM NotificationDatesForReport WHERE FormStatus = NR.FormStatus) AS [Total],
    NR.DisplayOrder
FROM
    NotificationDatesForReport AS NR
GROUP BY
    NR.FormStatus, NR.DisplayOrder  
UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Distinct password requests',
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests
        WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate()) AND dbo.DateNoTime(GetDate() + 1)) AS [Today],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ToEMail) FROM PasswordRequests) AS [Total],
    999999999 AS DisplayOrder

ORDER BY
    DisplayOrder
```

Here we are explicitly selecting the sort column in *every* part of the `UNION`, so that it is available to `ORDER BY` after the unioning is done. A suitable value for the `DisplayOrder` for the `Distinct password requests` row will of course depend on data type and application details.

Comment: I had thought of this but the problem is that the field DisplayOrder then appears in the resultant report unless I wrap this into another view

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the union all and put it into a temp table.. then sort it

like this

```
SELECT * INTO #TMPUNION FROM (
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM TABLE2
)

SELECT * FROM #TMPUNION
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME
```

make sure to check if tmptable exists

EDIT: I see you're trying to do something else.

Put the first table into a #tmptable with it sorted in the query.

then union the tmptable

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to sort one part of the script. I can sort the whole thing but the sort key is only in the first SELECT statement

Comment: Like i put in the edit.. insert the first SELECT into a tmp table with it ordered within the tmp table... then union that tmp table

Comment: Not sure why I was voted down. Inserting both into a tmp table then selecting your columns, sorting, etc would get the same result as putting them into a CTE

Comment: Hi, you were not voted down by me and your solution is viable. I'll vote you up one and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always 'cheat' a little bit where unions are concerned and put in an extra column in each of them for ordering.

```
; with unions as 
       (
       Select 
           c.name
       ,   c2.name
       ,   1 as 'Order'
       from table1 c 
           join table2 c2 on c.ID =c2.ID
       union
       select 
           c.name
       ,   c2.name
       ,   2
       from table3 c 
           join table4 c2 on c.ID =c2.ID
       )
select *
from unions
order by Order
```

If you wanted to get even more crazy and do some multi column ordering you could use a row_number over() windowed function in the first union block something like:

```
row_number over(partition by c.name order by c2.name) as Order
```

Generally when I want to sort union blocks I do something like this and put a row number placeholder pointer explicitly in and then either get the block of unions with either a nested select or wrap them in a CTE (as shown).